# Copy a CharArrayBuffer to another CharArrayBuffer

Tags: java, android

How can I copy a `CharArrayBuffer` to another `CharArrayBuffer` at a specified index in Java on Android?

developer.android.com/reference/android/…

```
CharArrayBuffer stringBuffer1 = new CharArrayBuffer(128); 
System.arraycopy("Phone", 0, stringBuffer1.data, 0, "Phone".length());
```

But i get an `ArrayStoreException`. I have allocated the `CharArrayBuffer` to be **128**. I don't understand this exception

Comment: What do you mean by CharArrayBuffer? There's a CharBuffer and a CharArrayReader/Writer, but I don't see a CharArrayBuffer.

Comment: CharArrayBuffer - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/CharArrayBuffer.html

Comment: or it could be: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/CharArrayBuffer.html It would be nice to know the context.

Comment: Sorry. I did not realize that it is an android specified class. I am using 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CharArrayBuffer.html

 CharArrayBuffer stringBuffer1 = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
System.arraycopy("Phone", 0, stringBuffer1.data, 0, "Phone".length());

But i get an ArrayStoreException.  I have allocated the CharArrayBuffer to be 128. I don't understand this exception

Comment: I see two CharArrayBuffers in the adroid docs: Apache commons and android.database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the docs

```
System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

*Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array.*

*ArrayStoreException*
Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an `ArrayStoreException`:

```
 Object x[] = new String[3];
 x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

following line of code

```
System.arraycopy("Phone", 0, stringBuffer1.data, 0, "Phone".length());
```

is trying to put String into `CharArrayBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayStoreException is because of a type.  Convert "Phone" into a CharArrayBuffer.  (The size of the array is not the issue.  It will throw a IndexOutOfBoundsException if it is.)